# Root finding with secant method of a black box function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have the following problem:

I have an algorithm, let's call if $r = F(μ)$. This algorithm consists of a gradient projection of a vector **j** on a vector **g**, a correction step a and a linear mapping of the resulting vector with a matrix **K**.

The input $μ$ is the multiplicator of a part of the **j**. The output ratio $r$ comprises of the infinity norm of part of the resulting vector in the nominator and the infinity norm of another part of the resulting vector in the denominator.

Hence, the function $F$ is non-linear, non-convex and probably non-differentiable.

I want now to make this ratio converge to a specific value $r^*$. So I am in effect trying to find the roots of the following function:

$$y(μ) = r^* - F(μ) = 0$$

I am looking only for positive values of $μ$. When μ changes sign, it greatly changes the physicsal meaning of my initial problem, which i don't want.

I use the secant method and it sometimes works; others it doesn't. I also apply an under-relaxation update rule:

$$μ_{k+1} += w^* μ_{k} + (1 - w)^* μ_{k+1}$$

where $w = 0.1\sim 0.3$.

This still does not help. It might converge sometimes, but others it greatly diverges. 
Next thing I would implement is the Aitken relaxation iteration, but I have a gut feeling it will not work either.

Some things about the $F(μ)$ that I have observed:

1. For tiny increments of $μ$, the output r usually converges in the correct value.
2. For bigger increments of $μ$, the output r barely changes, which in return gives me a zero gradient, which in return leads to a huge step update in the secant method, and boom! divergence.

Someone told me something about the $F(μ)$ being Lipschitz continuous in a tiny spectral radius around the intial $μ$ value. I do not know how to use this information though.

So question finally is:
Which method I can use to ensure convergence to a value near my initial one? I am 100% this problem has a solution, so it is a matter of convergence and using the right method. And how can I keep my $μ$ positive? Should I apply a constraint explicitly or is there an implict faster way?

Thanks!

Comment: So can your function $F$ be written as $F(\mu)=\frac{\|A\mu+B\|_\infty}{\|C\mu+D\|_\infty}$ where $A,B,C,D$ are vectors, or do the operations before taking the norms result in some rational function in $\mu$? // Did you try bracketing methods, like regula falsi illinois or Dekker's method?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, i can definitely write it like that, and i have. But i dont know how it would help me. No i haven't tried those, i was thinking about bisection method or Brennt's method.

Comment: These two are in the middle, both in most cases faster than bisection, but only using the secant root, not the inverse quadratic root like Brent. Illinois will do a "full" secant step and then an interval tightening step, while Dekker will more rarely do non-secant steps, and thus be faster (for more code complexity).// It might accelerate the root finding process to write the equation to solve as $f(\mu)=\|A\mu+B\|-r^*\|C\mu+D\|$, as this is now piecewise linear.

Comment: Sorry, had to delete previous comment because I could not delete it.
OK, I will try your proposed methods today! 
I have some new info, I am trying to run it now with an extremely small relaxation factor, w = 0.01. That makes steps taken tiny. It works like that, but takes 300 iterations to converge. Unfortunately in some cases the algorithm converges to a negative μ. How can I enforce non-negativity?

One more question: I read somewhere that the Aitken method is also called Secant Method in the literature. Does this mean that those two are equivalent for scalar problems?

Comment: Aitken's delta-square process transforms a linearly convergent fixed-point iteration into a Newton-like iteration, that converges superlinearly to quadratically. So yes, one can find a secant root in there, but I have never seen it. If you do not use a bracketing interval, you need to enforce the positivity manually, set $\mu=u^2$ or $\mu=e^u$ or similar.

Comment: I have tried the Illinois algorithm and it works really good if my initial guesses have opposing signs. The problem is though, how to find those initial values consistently. I have observed that the function is pretty constant and positive for most inputs, and then goes almost suddenly to a negative value around a specific input. 
Of course it is really hard to find this input in the first place. Are there maybe ways to do that consistently?

Comment: Here perhaps you can take the largest $|A_i|$ and the largest $|C_k|$ and just solve $|A_i\mu+B_i|=r^*|C_k\mu+D_k|$ to get an upper bound for the bracketing interval, as above that the two terms in $f(\mu)$ should not cross again.